# How to pass String into integer Pointer in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I have method which has `IntPtr` as parameter. Now I have a string "EXT101" which I need to pass into the function parameter as argument. Following is my function and what I tried but its not working.

```
unsafe private static extern int lineDevSpecific(IntPtr hLine);
```

```
string vline="Ext101"; 
int* hline=&vline;
```

How to pass `hline` as argument?

Comment: what are you going to achieve?

Comment: @Philipp Thnx sir for ur response .Sir i need to pass argument as int* in the function

Comment: You can make an int* point to a string?

Comment: It is not clear what `int*` represents.

Comment: @Patashu Sir how to make int* point to string..

Comment: int* means 'pointer to int'. If it pointed to a string, it would be string* :P

Comment: Right now it looks like hline points to the address of vline, but you don't show the code where it is dereferenced. That is the section that really matters but provided you simply point to the value at the address pointed to by hline it should be fine. Some IDE's will not like it though and throw a fatal error (normally the pointer should point to a type the same as the pointer type although technically it isn't necessary). So you should make  your pointer of type string if you want to do this properly.

Comment: @vikas: are you sure about the method signature ? If so, are you sure about its meaning ?

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix yes sir its windows telephony method for extended functinality

Comment: `"Ext101"` = `0x457874313031`. The only thing I can see a working version of above code doing is letting `hLine` point to the first 4 bytes = `"Ext1"` = `0x45787431` = `1165521969`, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: So does `lineDevSpecific()` call into unmanaged code via P/Invoke? If so, what is it P/Invoking? If not, what the *hell* is it doing being passed an IntPtr? BTW you are confusing an IntPtr (so named because it stores a pointer inside an int) with a pointer to an int.

Comment: are you trying to P/Invoke this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918530.aspx ? If so, the hline is a handle that is returned by another function call, and appears from the c# side as an IntPtr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say `EXT101` is a pre-processor defined constant.  There's no easy way of getting that, as it ceases to exist as a name after being compiled.  You'll need to take a look at the header file for whatever library you're trying to link with to find the value.

Answer (score 1):

Note that IntPtr isn't a pointer to int. It is pointer represented by signed native integer. Maybe you want to obtain the pointer to this string in memory:

```
string vline="Ext101";
IntPtr hline = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(vline);
lineDevSpecific(hline);
```